# $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\left[x\right]/\left\langle f\right\rangle $ is a semilocal ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, $f$ be a nonconstant polynomial that is contained in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\left[x\right]$. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\left[x\right]/\left\langle f\right\rangle $ is a semilocal ring.

Comment: Do you really mean $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (the ring of $p$-adics) or do you mean $\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the field with $p$ elements?

Comment: I think it isn't the ring of $p$-adics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n,$ then $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/\langle f\rangle$ only has $p^n$ elements, in particular a finite number. So there are only finitely many subsets...

Comment: @user109584: $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/\langle f\rangle$ only has $p^n$ elements. Can you show that $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/\langle f\rangle$ has finite maximal ideals?

Comment: The maximal ideals of $$\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/\langle f\rangle$$? What are they?

Comment: @user109584 You don't need to find the maximal ideals, you just need to show that there are finitely many. Ideals are subsets of the ring.

Answer (score 1):

We recall that the polynomial ring over a field is a PID, hence a Dedekind domain. In such a ring we have

$$I \subseteq J \iff I | J$$

and furthermore $(a) | (b) \iff a | b$. Hence we have that maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ that contain $f$ are in bijection with prime factors of $f$. How many prime factors does $f$ have?

Note this shows that for any field $F$, $F[x]/(f)$ for some non-constant polynomial $f$ has a finite number of maximal ideals.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $F$ is a field, then $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain. If $f\in F[x]$, what are the maximal ideals of $F[x]$ containing $\langle f\rangle$?

Comment: The maximal ideal of $F[x]$ is $<p(x)>$ for some irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ in $F[x]$.